# How to clear the console in sublime text 3 when running a new script?

Tags: python

I am trying to customize sublime text 3 for Python development. Is there a way to set my buildsystem to clear the console before running a script? Also, I would like to have my console opened by default when opening a new session. I'm using Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `ClearConsole` package in sublime, then type `alt+k` to clear then console.